# Apple Pay on web Merchant validation

Tags: applepayjs

I Managed to retrieve merchantSession object from Apple Pay server as below. I used Sandbox Test (Setup on itunesconnect and login the sandbox account on iphone and added tested visa card)

```
{
    "epochTimestamp":15065...20,
    "expiresAt":1506527672620,
    "merchantSessionIdentifier":"2EF498A9E...C24",
    "nonce":"f32....9",
    "merchantIdentifier":"7941CB932...DE2",
    "domainName":"mywebsite.com",
    "displayName":"My Test Shop",
    "signature":"30800609....0000"
}
```

However, in the Apple Pay pop-up sheet, it still stuck at "Processing", what do I need to do to able to process the next stage to show the "Touch Id"?

Also, below is my code snippet for onvalidatemerchant:

```
session.onvalidatemerchant = (event) => {
        console.log("Validate merchant");
        const validationURL = event.validationURL;
        getApplePaySession(event.validationURL).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            session.completeMerchantValidation(response);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Now if all the below are met, the payment sheet should be displayed on the iPhone. You should verify several things:

- Your Mac and iPhone are connected to the same iCloud test account
- Both are on the same WiFi
- HandOff is on
- AirDrop is on
- Bluetooth is on

A simple check to see if they are connected is to open a browser on the iPhone/Mac and see it on the other device.

Comment: The payment sheet displays on the iPhone, but it stuck in "Processing".

Comment: @user2249533 Hi, did you find the problem?

Comment: Can you share, please?

Comment: basically my error was due to I forgot to JSON.parse the string returned from Apple.